# How to start with db2 after installation

Tags: authentication, db2

I am new to db2. I have installed db2 and need to run the queries through terminal. I have LINUX machine.

After installed run the below query or any queries like create database, it will display the error

```
db2 => start database manager
SQL1092N  "ROOT" does not have the authority to perform the requested command 
or operation.
```

Answer (score 3):

The root user does not have automatic access to DB2 server resources, and arguably shouldn't. The user you should be logged in as to start working with DB2 is the instance owner (this is a different user than the DAS owner). If you're not sure which user owns the DB2 instance, or if an instance exists yet, use the db2ilist command to show a list of all instances installed on the local server.

As the db2 instance owner you can run db2start, db2stop, and db2sampl to start working with a database right away. Eventually you will want to create other users who will interact with DB2 with fewer permissions than the instance owner has. As soon as you have a database up and running, you can use GRANT statements to allow other users to connect to the database, work with tables, and execute routines (user-defined functions and stored procedures).

Answer (score 2):

This link can help you. (http://community.jboss.org/wiki/InstallDB2OnFedora)

Log in as dasusr. Use the db2admin command to control the administration server.

[dasusr]$ db2admin start
[dasusr]$ db2admin stop

Comment: Thank YOU so much Jasonw. The link is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Log in as a DB2ADMIN. Then add a user and give previllige for him.

[image]